# Как пересоздать меню в тулбаре в зависимости от выбранного пункта navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

Я пытаюсь сделать пересоздание менюшки на тулбаре. Чтобы можно было там отображать новые элементы с другими id. Пока я искал информацию в сети понял что можно чисто гипотетически удалять все элементы и добавлять новые с нужными id, тайтлами и так можно решить мою проблему. Но может быть можно как-то пересоздать меню чтобы в этой функции:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message_list_menu, menu);
      return true;
    }
```

можно было использовать не только одну эту строку:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message_list_menu, menu);
```

а сделать что-то типа такого:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        switch (menu_item) {
            case 1:
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message_list_menu, menu);
                break;

            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(this,"2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(this,"3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }


        return true;
    }
```

может есть какой-то более-менее работающий способ? Надеюсь что мне не прийдется удалять и добавлять элементы динамически.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в `Drawer`e вы вставляете фрагменты, почему бы просто не сделать кастомный `toolbar` и не показывать менюхи из фрагмента?

Примерно так:

в самом `drawer`

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Поиск");
        **searchItem.setVisible(false);**
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ну а во фрагменте где надо показать:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    item.setVisible(true);//показываем меню
}
```

и в `onCreateOptionsMenu` ставите свое меню.
Основную тему я ставлю `NoActionBar` и в разметке втыкаю вот так

```
 <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, вы учитывали что в navigationDrawer стоит framelayout и там уже мои фрагменты переключаются? потому что я не очень уверен что из фрагмента можно как-то влиять на меню в общем drawer.

Comment: Ну у меня такая схема работает, это как минимум.

Comment: Единственное, что в тех фрагментах где менюхи не нужны их придется прятать  item.setVisible(false);